# ListView in another ListView

Tags: android

can I have something like this:

¤list 1 element 1

¤¤list 2 element 1

¤¤list 2 element 2

¤¤ ...

¤list 1 element 2

¤¤list 3 element 1

¤¤  list 3 element 2

¤¤  ...

starting to wonder it's stupid as I write it

Comment: It looks like a tree structure to me.

Comment: true, it is not advisable to have list view inside a list view, what happens to scroll listener when you over lap two lists? think about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ExpandableListView`. Perfectly suits your needs. Refer the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a previous instance of this question along with a good answer:

[android nested listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135112/android-nested-listview)