# Android ListView that opens a subset

Tags: android, listview, subset

I would like to design an item like this that opens a subset of other items when clicked, I have only seen it in other applications I've used, and I can't find any resources on how to create it. Does anyone know how to?

Thanks.

[image: My objective]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear if you want to created Nested listviews that look like this

```
-Item1
-Item2
---Item2A
---Item2B
-Item3
```

or if you want to open a completely new list when the user clicks on an item.

If you want to use a nested listview look at this question: [android nested listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135112/android-nested-listview)

And if you want to open a new activity, then create a 2nd activity with a listview and open that on an item click

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to have a look at the `ExpandableListView`.

Documentation is available from here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

If you wanted to add a `ListView` that opens another list, you can do it in several ways. I've successfully done it by adding an `OnItemClickListener` to the `ListView` and then simply load a new set of data in the `ListView` and update it using `invalidate()` or by setting a new `Adapter`.

You could even add some cool transitions or animations, and create a listener for when the animation is completed. Lots of cool ideas :-)