# android: Nested View upto 3 Levels

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to make a view in android that can expand up to 3 levels. There are multiple grandparents. Each grandparent can have at least one or multiple parents. Each parent can have at least one or multiple children. To better understanding the problem, I am adding an image with this post. I guess it would be ExpanableListView control. I can make ExpandableListView up to 2 levels (mean parent and child) but how to make it up to 3 Levels?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about creating different layouts and then include layouts inside each other using the `<include>` tag?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135112/android-nested-listview) what about this. I think its more easy and appropriate. What do you say?

Comment: Yeah. But how come you hadn't searched it before putting up this question?

Comment: I think Paulo Cesar suggested solution says that there is a LinearLayout at every row of ListView and on "binding" find LinearLayout and add controls to it for nested items

Comment: Seems to be the solution you're looking for. All the best.

Comment: I didnt find this link before thats why I put a question here but couldnt find any satisfiable answer. So, I searched again and found this.

Comment: @MudasserHassan so what did you find?

Comment: @noloman I've found the link given in my 1st comment. Please check that link.