# Are nested ListViews Vertical and Horizontal possible?

Tags: android

I have taken the HorizontalListView code from DevSmartLib and tried to insert this into a stock Android ListView without much success.  I keep ending up with an empty ListView.   I am using two setAdapter calls:  One for the main activity (Vertical) ListView and the other for filling the DevSmartLib HorizontaListView with its individual elements.  The second setAdapter is called in the getView method of the adapter for the (Vertical) ListView.

Can anyone suggest an approach or has anyone got this to work?  I have been tryiing for a while.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [StackFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135112/android-nested-listview) it is not possible.  However, the solution there does not meet my needs.