# Android - Nested ListView Alternatives?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on an Android app in which user can view/put comment to a post. I am using a similar screen capture from Vine to illustrate my question:

[image: Vine]

In the main screen of Vine, There is a big ListView contains post items (and each post includes the short video, profile picture, number of people like it, etc. Like the one shown in the image), and each post item contains a small list (marked by red line) that contains the comments.

I am asking for some pointers to a good way of implementing this red-lined list. Is it good to be implemented as a nested ListView inside the post list item? Will nested ListView affect performance? Is there other recommended way to implement this if not using nested ListView?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135112/android-nested-listview?rq=1

Comment: Check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html. With a proper design in UI you can make your list as you want, the red-line part will be the child time.