# How to use nested Listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I need to show data which contains a main object and has many child objects. Each child object has its view which contains checkbox and buttons having functionality. Giving demo design which I've done

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELB51.png

But am not understanding how to create nested listview to populate data in this way. Picture showing 'Reminder 01' is first reminder data and there will be many reminder data each having their own doses data with checkbox and snooze button. Even I've done all logic and getting data but don't know how to populate data in nested listview. Please give me efficient suggestion.

Comment: Here's what you're looking for : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: I will try that but is it will be ok to use use custom layout containing imageview and text as expandable header layout ? Design have to be same as I've shown

Comment: Nope, you define 2 xml, one for "parents" (ie categories) and one for children

Comment: can you give me any reference example if possible ?

Comment: Here's one : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/    Here's another one (better probably) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview

Comment: Thanks @NicolasSimon i will go through it

Comment: check the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40365617/6212796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Cards Lib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)

**Examples**:

- [Card With
  List](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDWITHLIST.md)
- [Cardexpand-And-CardListView](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/EXPAND.md#cardexpand-and-cardlistview)

And you can customize the card's internal layout to use according to what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on it and let you know about update

Answer (score 0):

You need an ExpandableListView backed by an ExpandableListAdapter. Here is a sample ExpandableListAdapter from an app that I worked on for practice sometime back (simply use it as an example as it was not designed with efficiency in mind) - [Sample ExpandableListAdapter](https://github.com/ucsunil/android-todo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/application/adapters/TaskTreeAdapter.java). You can go through the layouts to see how I used them.

You will go about the same as you would by binding a normal ListView to an instance class that extends BaseAdapter but instead you will bind your ExpandableListView to an instance of a class that extends [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on it and let you know about update.